# Redux "pure" functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I explored redux lately and was curious - does payload field of action let functions 'action-creator' call pure?
I mean we can possibly put in payload any variables, even input values and etc. but cause by rules reducer need to be pure function it couldn't be absolutely `pure` - it depends on "impure" actions. Is it something like an agreement or assumption to make things easier? Or "pure" rules are not for function creators?

PS: sorry if that was too a stupid question. I'm still just learning

Comment: Does the function return the same output with the same input and produces no side-effects?

Comment: The agreement is that redux action should be serializable. Just data. Nothing prevent you from sending anything you want tho. But try to not dispatch native event, stream, promises, etc, and instead just dispatch plain javascript object.

Answer (score 1):

In computer programming, a pure function is a function that has the following properties:

1. Its return value is the same for the same arguments (no variation with local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input streams from I/O devices).
2. Its evaluation has no side effects (no mutation of local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or I/O streams)

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function

This is a pure function

`const sum = (a, b) => a + b`

This is not a pure function as it relies on an value outside its scope

`const getWindowHeight = () => window.innerHeight`

This is also not pure because of the side effect fetch causes

`const sendData = (url) => { fetch(url)  return true }`

In relation to redux your action creators should always be pure. A thunk is unlikely to be pure as it could have side effects. Reducers are always pure as they take in the state, create a new state and return it, no mutation of existing state.